# Notify all clients about a change

Tags: c#, node.js, server

so I'm in a little project of mine and for now the client gets some information it needs using requests, more precisely requesting the data to a nodejs server running express. The thing is I want that when 1 client alters something every connected client gets a notification that something just changed. How could I do this? I'm new to all this networking stuff so any help is appreciated.
Also the client is a C# Windows Forms

Comment: Follow any [chat tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) that uses socket.io and node.js

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it can be achieved via the publisher-subscriber design pattern. Where each client will subscribe to an event and listen to it (perform an action on it) whenever there's an event being broadcasted. I suggest you take a look at [the pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) and see how others have implemented it particularly to your situation.

You can take a look at [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) which is "a library that enables real-time, bidirectional and event-based communication between the browser and the server."